# How to specific a certain row in an XML based Jasper Report

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

I'm trying to use an XML data source iReport Template, however, I need to call out certain rows in Jasper from a listed object.

```
<week-dates>
  <date dayNumber="1" iso="2021-07-12" formatted="07/11/2021" dayOfWeek="SUNDAY" dayOfWeekShort="Sun"/>
  <date dayNumber="2" iso="2021-07-13" formatted="07/12/2021" dayOfWeek="MONDAY" dayOfWeekShort="Mon"/>
  <date dayNumber="3" iso="2021-07-14" formatted="07/13/2021" dayOfWeek="TUESDAY" dayOfWeekShort="Tue"/>
  <date dayNumber="4" iso="2021-07-15" formatted="07/14/2021" dayOfWeek="WEDNESDAY" dayOfWeekShort="Wed"/>
  <date dayNumber="5" iso="2021-07-16" formatted="07/15/2021" dayOfWeek="THURSDAY" dayOfWeekShort="Thu"/>
  <date dayNumber="6" iso="2021-07-17" formatted="07/16/2021" dayOfWeek="FRIDAY" dayOfWeekShort="Fri"/>
  <date dayNumber="7" iso="2021-07-18" formatted="07/17/2021" dayOfWeek="SATURDAY" dayOfWeekShort="Sat"/>
</week-dates>
```

I can get the first object, using `week-dates/date/@iso` inside the page header band, But this should be used to iterate through the object in the detail band. However, I need fields to specifically call out certain rows, for example `week-dates/date/iso[2]` to call out iso date from dayNumber 3. However, I can't seem to get that to work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get a specific line in this list so I can use text fields in horizontal order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `week-dates/date[5]/@iso` will work for this specific example, it may be a better idea to specify "the date element that has a dayNumber attribute equal to 5" in the XPath.

`week-dates/date[@dayNumber=5]/@iso`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the element index needed to be on the date element, not the iso level

`week-dates/date[5]/@iso`

Gave the expected result